# Number of divisors of a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a number $n$ , let $m$ denote the number of divisors of $n$. Is there a way to express the number of divisors of $n^2$ explicitly through $m$ without using the powers of primes in the factorization of $n$.

Comment: 6 and 8 have the same number of divisors. 36 and 64 don't.

Answer (score 1):

$$n=\prod_{j=1}^k\big(p_j\big)^{a_j}\qquad\quad=>\qquad{\boxed{\quad\begin{align}m&=\prod_{j=1}^k\big(a_j+1\big)\\n^2&=\prod_{j=1}^k\big(p_j\big)^{2a_j}\qquad\quad=>\qquad\quad M=\prod_{j=1}^k\big(2a_j+1\big)\end{align}}}$$

$$=>\qquad M=2^k\cdot\prod_{j=1}^k\bigg(a_j+\frac12\bigg)<2^k\cdot m$$ Does this suffice for a **rough** estimate of an **upper** limit ?